# Differentiating and lagging values of one df

Tags: r, sapply

I have a df of stock prices and I would like to calculate the return, hence I need to calculate today's value - yesterdays' for every lag.
Moreover I want this to be lagged by 1 day ´since I wan to know how yesterdays return influenced my decision today. 
I tried `sapply(importData, function(x) diff(x) / lag(x, k=-1))` 
But this somehow gives me completely different values than I would expect.

Here is an example value:
Stock 1 has the value 16.49 for today and 16.32 yesterday, hence I would expect a value of 0.17 in the cell before yesterdays' value, since it is lagged by 1. But the formula gives me a -0.031.

I guess I must have understood the code wrong, can someone help me out here?

Edit: here is some testdata
Time |Stock 1
day 1|18.85
day 2|18.32
day3|18.49

so my outcome should be 18.49-18.32 = `0.17` and since this result is lagged by 1 it should be in the cell where the value for `day1` is now.

Comment: I think you only need `diff(x)`

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is not possible to say for sure, but this may be related to the behavior of base R's `lag` function. This function takes in "A vector or matrix or univariate or multivariate time series."

Comment: @Christoph You are absolutely right. I got the needed results. But since `lag(x)` only changes the time and not the value it should just lead to a value lagged twice instead of a completely different value, no?

Comment: I never used `lag`. Please provide testdata. Then I might be able to help.

Comment: But I still need it to be lagged by 1 day. Since `lag(x)`doesn't seem to do the trick, does anyone have a sugestion on how I might be able to do that?

Comment: `lag` doesn't change the location of the result vector.  You're expecting the results to be shifted, where `lag` just takes the value at the position lagged by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these.  Except for the last one no packages are used.

**1) plain vector**

```
x <- c(2, 2.1, 2.2)
c(NA, diff(x) / x[-length(x)])
## [1] NA 0.05000000 0.04761905
```

Double check:

```
c(NA, (2.1 - 2)/2, (2.2 - 2.1)/2.1)
## [1] NA  0.05000000 0.04761905
```

**1a) log approximation**

```
diff(log(x))
## [1] 0.04879016 0.04652002
```

`diff(log(x))` is based on the following where the last equals is really approximately equals and is based on the approximation log(x) = x-1 if x is close to 1.  For example, log(1.01) = 0.009950331 which is close to 1.01 - 1 = .01.

```
diff(log(x)) 
= c(log(x[2]) - log(x[1]), log(x[3]) - log(x[2])) 
= c(log(x[2]/x[1]), log(x[3]/x[2])) 
= c(x[2]/x[1] - 1, x[3]/x[2] - 1)    (approximately)
```

**2) ts time series**

```
tt <- ts(c(2, 2.1, 2.2)
diff(tt) / lag(tt, -1)
## Time Series:
## Start = 2 
## End = 3 
## Frequency = 1 
## [1] 0.05000000 0.04761905
```

**3) zoo time series**

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(c(2, 2.1, 2.2))
diff(z, arithmetic = FALSE) - 1
##          2          3 
## 0.05000000 0.04761905
```

Comment: Thank you for the good overview but I don't quite get the math behind your example. Lets do 1) here 2.2-2.1 is 0.1 hence the field that is currently occupied by NA should have the value of o.1 in it since the difference = return and then rewinding it a day puts it one position "earlier" in the timeline.

Comment: Have clarified by writing it out.  If we want the answer to be of the same length as the input then first value is NA since there is no value before the first thus the return of the first value cannot be calculated.  The return of the first non-NA value will be (2.1 - 2)/2.  In the question you asked for the "return".  The first non-NA return is (2.1-2)/2.   In contrast the numerator, 2.1-2 is the difference, not the return.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to lag values use `dplyr`s function `lag`. See below

```
set.seed(1000)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(exp = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
                 x = rnorm(6, 2, 3))
df %>% group_by(exp) %>% mutate(x1 = lag(x))
```

with your example

```
df <- data.frame(day = c("d1", "d2", "d3"), val = c(18.85, 18.32, 18.49))
df  %>% mutate(val1 = lag(val))
```

you got

```
  day   val  val1
1  d1 18.85    NA
2  d2 18.32 18.85
3  d3 18.49 18.32
```

the `lead`function works opposite to `lag`